# Gravitational light bending and refraction?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, experimental-physics, refraction, gravitational-lensing

I've trying to read up on the evidential merit of general relativity and am rather curious as well as skeptical of early as well of possibly later more rigorous measurements of light (electromagnetic signals) bending around the bodies in our solar system. In all situations, but especially around the sun, how have we accounted for errors invoked by purely classical (or quantum) light refraction in the atmosphere of the sun (planets or space) which would affect electromagnetic signals being sent/received or see light from distant stars. I would love it if someone did some calculations on what we would expect the deflection to be purely from refraction and then what we expect from GTR then what was experimentally measured. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: You might do well to look into the gravitational lensing due to galactic clusters, and try doing some calculations based on the density of intergalactic gas and the resulting difference between the refractive index of that and a pure vacuum.  Maybe try a spherical distribution that decreases at a reasonable rate from a central point.  Google "distributed index lens"  for how-to.

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled by your question, because certainly the easiest, and most standard, way to show the bending of light in general relativity is to use refraction (classical or quantum wave treatment does not affect the argument. For example, here is the diagram which I use to explain the calculation in [The Mathematics of Gravity and Quanta](http://www.troubador.co.uk/bookshop/computing-science-education/light-after-dark-iii/)

[image]

Iirc Einstein also used refraction. The bending can also be calculated by using the equation of a geodesic, with more effort and exactly the same result.

The only difference between this and any other argument using refraction is that the change to the speed of light is a result from the choice of coordinates used to describe Schwarzschild geometry, not from the slowing of light in a medium.

For light which just touches the Sun, the bending is 1.75 seconds of arc, and of course we can measure the bending on other trajectories. Bending of radio waves has been confirmed to within 0.03% of the prediction using very long baseline interferometry.

We do, of course, calculate and take into account any errors due to gas, but this is so much smaller than the observed bending that I do not think you should worry about it.